# Forwarding to in-place constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I have a message class which was previously a bit of a pain to work with, you had to construct the message class, tell it to allocate space for your object and then populate the space either by construction or memberwise.

I want to make it possible to construct the message object with an immediate, inline new of the resulting object, but to do so with a simple syntax at the call site while ensuring copy elision.

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef uint8_t id_t;
enum class MessageID { WorldPeace };

class Message
{
    uint8_t* m_data;         // current memory
    uint8_t m_localData[64]; // upto 64 bytes.
    id_t m_messageId;
    size_t m_size; // amount of data used
    size_t m_capacity; // amount of space available
    // ...

public:
    Message(size_t requestSize, id_t messageId)
        : m_data(m_localData)
        , m_messageId(messageId)
        , m_size(0), m_capacity(sizeof(m_localData))
    {
        grow(requestSize);
    }

    void grow(size_t newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > m_capacity)
        {
            m_data = realloc((m_data == m_localData) ? nullptr : m_data, newSize);
            assert(m_data != nullptr); // my system uses less brutal mem mgmt
            m_size = newSize;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* allocatePtr()
    {
        size_t offset = size;
        grow(offset + sizeof(T));
        return (T*)(m_data + offset);
    }

#ifdef USE_CPP11
    template<typename T, typename Args...>
    Message(id_t messageId, Args&&... args)
        : Message(sizeof(T), messageID)
    {
        // we know m_data points to a large enough buffer
        new ((T*)m_data) T (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
#endif
};
```

Pre-C++11 I had a nasty macro, CONSTRUCT_IN_PLACE, which did:

```
#define CONSTRUCT_IN_PLACE(Message, Typename, ...) \
    new ((Message).allocatePtr<Typename>()) Typename (__VA_ARGS__)
```

And you would say:

```
Message outgoing(sizeof(MyStruct), MessageID::WorldPeace);
CONSTRUCT_IN_PLACE(outgoing, MyStruct, wpArg1, wpArg2, wpArg3);
```

With C++11, you would use

```
Message outgoing<MyStruct>(MessageID::WorldPeace, wpArg1, wpArg2, wpArg3);
```

But I find this to be messy. What I want to implement is:

```
    template<typename T>
    Message(id_t messageId, T&& src)
        : Message(sizeof(T), messageID)
    {
        // we know m_data points to a large enough buffer
        new ((T*)m_data) T (src);
    }
```

So that the user uses

```
Message outgoing(MessageID::WorldPeace, MyStruct(wpArg1, wpArg2, wpArg3));
```

But it seems that this first constructs a temporary `MyStruct` on the stack turning the in-place `new` into a call to the move constructor of T.

Many of these messages are simple, often POD, and they are often in marshalling functions like this:

```
void dispatchWorldPeace(int wpArg1, int wpArg2, int wpArg3)
{
    Message outgoing(MessageID::WorldPeace, MyStruct(wpArg1, wpArg2, wpArg3));
    outgoing.send(g_listener);
}
```

So I want to avoid creating an intermediate temporary that is going to require a subsequent move/copy.

It seems like the compiler should be able to eliminate the temporary and the move and forward the construction all the way down to the in-place `new`.

What am I doing that is causing it not to? (GCC 4.8.1, Clang 3.5, MSVC 2013)

Comment: `Message w(id, in_place<MyStruct>(a,b,c));` do? Oh and a `std::forward<T>(src)` in the `new` would not hurt.

Comment: It might, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Oh - the missing forward might be it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't it be `template<typename T, typename... Args>
    Message(id_t messageId, Args&&... args)`? Doesn't seem to compile otherwise.

Comment: @remyabel Oops, should be fixed.

Comment: @Yakk When I make it use std::forward, it no-longer allows `Message(id, *this);` because it doesn't allow a [non-const] reference type.

Comment: @kfsone Why would it not?  I do not get why it fails.  Compiler?  Error message?  `T`?

Comment: Wait, is the class or constructor `template`ed?

Comment: @Yakk I have use cases of `uint32_t maxID; /*...*/ Message outgoing(MessageID::X, maxID);`, `Message outgoing(MessageID::Y, *this);` and `Message outgoing(MessageID::Z, SomeStruct(args);`. The problem was that I was specifying `T&& src` in the `Message::Message` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to elide the copy/move in the placement new: copy elision is entirely based on the idea that the compiler knows at construction time where the object will eventually end up. Also, since copy elision actually changes the behavior of the program (after all, it won't call the respective constructor and the destructor even if they have side-effects) copy elision is limited to a few very specific cases (listed in 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 31: essentially when returning a local variable by name, when throwing a local variable by name, when catching an exception of the correct type by value, and when copying/moving a temporary variable; see the clause for exact details). Since [placement] `new` is none of the contexts where the copy can be elided and the argument to constructor is clearly not a temporary (it is named), the copy/move will never be elided. Even adding the missing `std::forward<T>(...)` to your constructor will cause the copy/move to be elided:

```
template<typename T>
Message(id_t messageId, T&& src)
    : Message(sizeof(T), messageID)
{
    // placement new take a void* anyway, i.e., no need to cast
    new (m_data) T (std::forward<T>(src));
}
```

I don't think you can explicitly specify a template parameter when calling a constructor. Thus, I think the closest you could probably get without constructing the object ahead of time and getting it copied/moved is something like this:

```
template <typename>
struct Tag {};

template <typename T, typename A>
Message::Message(Tag<T>, id_t messageId, A... args)
    : Message(messageId, sizeof(T)) {
    new(this->m_data) T(std::forward<A>(args)...);
}
```

One approach which might make things a bit nicer is using the `id_t` to map to the relevant type assuming that there is a mapping from message Ids to the relevant type:

```
typedef uint8_t id_t;
template <typename T, id_t id> struct Tag {};
struct MessageId {
    static constexpr Tag<MyStruct, 1> WorldPeace;
    // ...
};
template <typename T, id_t id, typename... A>
Message::Message(Tag<T, id>, A&&... args)
    Message(id, sizeof(T)) {
    new(this->m_data) T(std::forward<A>)(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Foreword

The conceptual barrier that even C++2049 cannot cross is that you require all the bits that compose your message to be aligned in a contiguous memory block.

The only way C++ can give you that is through the use of the **placement new** operator. Otherwise, objects will simply be constructed according to their storage class (on the stack or through whatever you define as a new operator).

It means any object you pass to your payload constructor will be first constructed (on the stack) and then used by the constructor (that will most likely copy-construct it).

Avoiding this copy completely is impossible. You may have a forward constructor doing the minimal amount of copy, but still the scalar parameters passed to the initializer will likely be copied, as will any data that the constructor of the initializer deemed necessary to memorize and/or produce.

If you want to be able to pass parameters freely to each of the constructors needed to build the complete message without them being first stored in the parameter objects, it will require

- the use of a placement new operator for each of the sub-objects that compose the message,
- the memorization of each single scalar parameter passed to the various sub-constructors,
- specific code for each object to feed the placement new operator with the proper address and call the constructor of the sub-object.

You will end up with a toplevel message constructor taking all possible initial parameters and dispatching them to the various sub-objects constructors.

I don't even know if this is feasible, but the result would be very fragile and error-prone at any rate.

Is that what you want, just for the benefit of a bit of syntactic sugar?

If you're offering an API, you cannot cover all cases. The best approach is to make something that degrades nicely, IMHO.

The simple solution would be to limit payload constructor parameters to scalar values or implement "in-place sub-construction" for a limited set of message payloads that you can control. At your level you cannot do more than that to make sure the message construction proceeds with no extra copies.

Now the application software will be free to define constructors that take objects as parameters, and then the price to pay will be these extra copies.

Besides, this might be the most efficient approach, if the parameter is something costly to construct (i.e. the construction time is greater than the copy time, so it is more efficient to create a static object and modify it slightly between each message) or if it has a greater lifetime than your function for any reason.

#### a working, ugly solution

First, let's start with a vintage, template-less solution that does in-place construction.

The idea is to have the message pre-allocate the right kind of memory (local buffer of dynamic) depending on the size of the object.
The proper base address is then passed to a placement new to construct the message contents in place.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

typedef uint8_t id_t;
enum class MessageID { WorldPeace, Armaggedon };

#define SMALL_BUF_SIZE 64

class Message {
    id_t     m_messageId;
    uint8_t* m_data;
    uint8_t  m_localData[SMALL_BUF_SIZE];

public:

    // choose the proper location for contents
    Message (MessageID messageId, size_t size)
    {
        m_messageId = (id_t)messageId;
        m_data = size <= SMALL_BUF_SIZE ? m_localData : new uint8_t[size];
    }

    // dispose of the contents if need be
    ~Message ()
    {
        if (m_data != m_localData) delete m_data;
    }

    // let placement new know about the contents location
    void * location (void)
    {
        return m_data;
    }
};

// a macro to do the in-place construction
#define BuildMessage(msg, id, obj, ...   )       \
        Message msg(MessageID::id, sizeof(obj)); \
        new (msg.location()) obj (__VA_ARGS__);  \

// example uses
struct small {
    int a, b, c;
    small (int a, int b, int c) :a(a),b(b),c(c) {}
};
struct big {
    int lump[1000];
};

int main(void)
{
    BuildMessage(msg1, WorldPeace, small, 1, 2, 3)
    BuildMessage(msg2, Armaggedon, big)
}
```

This is just a trimmed down version of your initial code, with no templates at all.

I find it relatively clean and easy to use, but to each his own.

The only inefficiency I see here is the static allocation of 64 bytes that will be useless if the message is too big.

And of course all type information is lost once the messages are constructed, so accessing their contents afterward would be awkward.

#### About forwarding and construction in place

Basically, the new && qualifier does no magic. To do in-place construction, the compiler needs to know the address that will be used for object storage before calling the constructor.

Once you've invoked an object creation, the memory has been allocated and the && thing will only allow you to use that address to pass ownership of the said memory to another object without resorting to useless copies.

You can use templates to recognize a call to the `Message` constructor involving a given class passed as message contents, but that will be too late: the object will have been constructed before your constructor can do anything about its memory location.

I can't see a way to create a template on top of the `Message` class that would defer an object construction until you have decided at which location you want to construct it.

However, you could work on the classes defining the object contents to have some in-place construction automated.

**This will not solve the general problem of passing objects to the constructor of the object that will be built in place.**

To do that, you would need the sub-objects themselves to be constructed through a placement new, which would mean implementing a specific template interface for each of the initializers, and have each object provide the address of construction to each of its sub-objects.

#### Now for syntactic sugar.

To make the ugly templating worth the while, you can specialize your message classes to handle big and small messages differently.

The idea is to have a single lump of memory to pass to your sending function. So in case of small messages, the message header and contents are defined as local message properties, and for big ones, extra memory is allocated to include the message header.

Thus the magic DMA used to propell your messages through the system will have a clean data block to work with either way.

Dynamic allocations will still occur once per big message, and never for small ones.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <new>

// ==========================================================================
// Common definitions
// ==========================================================================

// message header
enum class MessageID : uint8_t { WorldPeace, Armaggedon };
struct MessageHeader {
    MessageID id;
    uint8_t   __padding; // one free byte here
    uint16_t  size;
};

// small buffer size
#define SMALL_BUF_SIZE 64

// dummy send function
int some_DMA_trick(int destination, void * data, uint16_t size);

// ==========================================================================
// Macro solution
// ==========================================================================

// -----------------------------------------
// Message class
// -----------------------------------------
class mMessage {
    // local storage defined even for big messages
    MessageHeader   m_header;
    uint8_t         m_localData[SMALL_BUF_SIZE];

    // pointer to the actual message
    MessageHeader * m_head;
public:  
    // choose the proper location for contents
    mMessage (MessageID messageId, uint16_t size)
    {
        m_head = size <= SMALL_BUF_SIZE 
            ? &m_header
            : (MessageHeader *) new uint8_t[size + sizeof (m_header)];
        m_head->id   = messageId;
        m_head->size = size;
   }

    // dispose of the contents if need be
    ~mMessage ()
    {
        if (m_head != &m_header) delete m_head;
    }

    // let placement new know about the contents location
    void * location (void)
    {
        return m_head+1;
    }

    // send a message
    int send(int destination)
    {
        return some_DMA_trick (destination, m_head, (uint16_t)(m_head->size + sizeof (m_head)));
    }
};

// -----------------------------------------
// macro to do the in-place construction
// -----------------------------------------
#define BuildMessage(msg, obj, id, ...   )       \
        mMessage msg (MessageID::id, sizeof(obj)); \
        new (msg.location()) obj (__VA_ARGS__);  \

// ==========================================================================
// Template solution
// ==========================================================================
#include <utility>

// -----------------------------------------
// template to check storage capacity
// -----------------------------------------
template<typename T>
struct storage
{
    enum { local = sizeof(T)<=SMALL_BUF_SIZE };
};

// -----------------------------------------
// base message class
// -----------------------------------------
class tMessage {
protected:
    MessageHeader * m_head;
    tMessage(MessageHeader * head, MessageID id, uint16_t size) 
        : m_head(head)
    {
        m_head->id = id;
        m_head->size = size;
    }
public:
    int send(int destination)
    {
        return some_DMA_trick (destination, m_head, (uint16_t)(m_head->size + sizeof (*m_head)));
    }
};

// -----------------------------------------
// general message template
// -----------------------------------------
template<bool local_storage, typename message_contents>
class aMessage {};

// -----------------------------------------
// specialization for big messages
// -----------------------------------------
template<typename T>
class aMessage<false, T> : public tMessage
{
public:
    // in-place constructor
    template<class... Args>
    aMessage(MessageID id, Args...args) 
        : tMessage(
            (MessageHeader *)new uint8_t[sizeof(T)+sizeof(*m_head)], // dynamic allocation
            id, sizeof(T))
    {
        new (m_head+1) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // destructor
    ~aMessage ()
    {
        delete m_head;
    }

    // syntactic sugar to access contents
    T& contents(void) { return *(T*)(m_head+1); }
};

// -----------------------------------------
// specialization for small messages
// -----------------------------------------
template<typename T>
class aMessage<true, T> : public tMessage
{
    // message body defined locally
    MessageHeader m_header;
    uint8_t       m_data[sizeof(T)]; // no need for 64 bytes here

public:
    // in-place constructor
    template<class... Args>
    aMessage(MessageID id, Args...args) 
        : tMessage(
            &m_header, // local storage
            id, sizeof(T))
    {
        new (m_head+1) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // syntactic sugar to access contents
    T& contents(void) { return *(T*)(m_head+1); }
};


// -----------------------------------------
// helper macro to hide template ugliness
// -----------------------------------------
#define Message(T) aMessage<storage<T>::local, T>
// something like typedef aMessage<storage<T>::local, T> Message<T>

// ==========================================================================
// Example
// ==========================================================================
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

// message sending
int some_DMA_trick(int destination, void * data, uint16_t size)
{
    printf("sending %d bytes @%p to %08X\n", size, data, destination);
    return 1;
}

// some dynamic contents
struct gizmo {
    char * s;
    gizmo(void) { s = nullptr; };
    gizmo (const gizmo&  g) = delete;

    gizmo (const char * msg)
    {
        s = new char[strlen(msg) + 3];
        strcpy(s, msg);
        strcat(s, "#");
    }

    gizmo (gizmo&& g)
    {
        s = g.s;
        g.s = nullptr;
        strcat(s, "*");
    }

    ~gizmo() 
    { 
        delete s;
    }

    gizmo& operator=(gizmo g)
    {
        std::swap(s, g.s);
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(gizmo& g)
    {
        return strcmp (s, g.s) != 0;
    }

};

// some small contents
struct small {
    int a, b, c;
    gizmo g;
    small (gizmo g, int a, int b, int c)
        : a(a), b(b), c(c), g(std::move(g)) 
    {
    }

    void trace(void) 
    { 
        printf("small: %d %d %d %s\n", a, b, c, g.s);
    }
};

// some big contents
struct big {
    gizmo lump[1000];

    big(const char * msg = "?")
    { 
        for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(lump) / sizeof(lump[0]); i++)
            lump[i] = gizmo (msg);
    }

    void trace(void)
    {
        printf("big: set to ");
        gizmo& first = lump[0];
        for (size_t i = 1; i != sizeof(lump) / sizeof(lump[0]); i++)
            if (lump[i] != first) { printf(" Erm... mostly "); break; }
        printf("%s\n", first.s);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    // macros
    BuildMessage(mmsg1, small, WorldPeace, gizmo("Hi"), 1, 2, 3);
    BuildMessage(mmsg2, big  , Armaggedon, "Doom");
    ((small *)mmsg1.location())->trace();
    ((big   *)mmsg2.location())->trace();
    mmsg1.send(0x1000);
    mmsg2.send(0x2000);

    // templates
    Message (small) tmsg1(MessageID::WorldPeace, gizmo("Hello"), 4, 5, 6);
    Message (big  ) tmsg2(MessageID::Armaggedon, "Damnation");
    tmsg1.contents().trace();
    tmsg2.contents().trace();
    tmsg1.send(0x3000);
    tmsg2.send(0x4000);
}
```

output:

```
small: 1 2 3 Hi#*
big: set to Doom#
sending 20 bytes @0xbf81be20 to 00001000
sending 4004 bytes @0x9e58018 to 00002000
small: 4 5 6 Hello#**
big: set to Damnation#
sending 20 bytes @0xbf81be0c to 00003000
sending 4004 bytes @0x9e5ce50 to 00004000
```

#### Arguments forwarding

I see little point in doing constructor parameters forwarding here.

Any bit of dynamic data referenced by the message contents would have to be either static or copied into the message body, otherwise the referenced data would vanish as soon as the message creator would go out of scope.

If the users of this wonderfully efficient library start passing around magic pointers and other global data inside messages, I wonder how the global system performance will like that. But that's none of my business, after all.

#### Macros

I resorted to a macro to hide the template ugliness in type definition.

If someone has an idea to get rid of it, I'm interested.

#### Efficiency

The template variation requires an extra forwarding of the contents parameters to reach the constructor. I can't see how that could be avoided.

The macro version wastes 68 bytes of memory for big messages, and some memory for small ones (`64 - sizeof (contents object)`).

Performance-wise, this extra bit of memory is the only gain the templates offer. Since all these objects are supposedly constructed on the stack and live for a handful of microseconds, it is pretty neglectible.

Compared to your initial version, this one should handle message sending more efficiently for big messages. Here again, if these messages are rare and only offered for convenience, the difference is not terribly useful.

The template version maintains a single pointer to the message payload, that could be spared for small messages if you implemented a specialized version of the `send` function.
Hardly worth the code duplication, IMHO.

#### A last word

I think I know pretty well how an operating system works and what performances concerns might be. I wrote quite a few real-time applications, plus some drivers and a couple of BSPs in my time.

I also saw more than once a very efficient system layer ruined by too permissive an interface that allowed application software programmers to do the silliest things without even knowing.
That is what triggered my initial reaction.

If I had my say in global system design, I would forbid all these magic pointers and other under-the-hood mingling with object references, to limit *non-specialist* users to an inoccuous use of system layers, instead of allowing them to inadvertently spread cockroaches through the system.

Unless the users of this interface are template and real-time savvies, they will not understand a bit what is going on beneath the syntactic sugar crust, and might very soon shoot themselves (and their co-workers and the application software) in the foot.

Suppose a poor application software programmer adds a puny field in one of its structs and crosses unknowingly the 64 bytes barrier. All of a sudden the system performance will crumble, and you will need Mr template & real time expert to explain the poor guy that what he did killed a lot of kittens.
Even worse, the system degradation might be progressive or unnoticeable at first, so one day you might wake up with thousands of lines of code that did dynamic allocations for years without anybody noticing, and the global overhaul to correct the problem might be huge.

If, on the other hand, all people in your company are munching at templates and mutexes for breakfast, syntactic sugar is not even required in the first place.

Comment: So, yeah. Not really sure where to start. So I'll just pick the most obvious and egregious. `if (m_data == m_localData) m_data = new uint8_t[new_size]; ... else m_data = (uint8_t*) realloc (m_data, new_size);`. Lets trim that down: `if X new ELSE realloc` and the ternary variant I wrote allows GCC, ICC, Clang and MSVC to use conditional assignment rather than a branch. And how do you consider allocating an object with "new" and memcpying it into the message *not a copy*? Plus the minor point that your code doesn't provide for in-place construction.

Comment: In my *sscce* I accidentally left `grow` as public - I didn't see the point in specifically going and marking it `private` for an *sscce*. In terms of the default "local buffer", the actual code pools these objects and a large percentage of the messages, especially in high pressure situations, are generally small enough to fit in those buffers.

The overarching reason for the complexity in this system is the large number of downstream users. The intent here is to work with the compiler sufficiently so that the immediate users of the API don't have to learn this kind of optimization nastiness.

Comment: The grow() method is never called in the constructor. I only included it to match what I understood of the original request. Objects less than 64 bytes in size are indeed copied (which takes a neglectible time), but larger ones are not. If you want to "grow" the message afterwards (which is an ungodly thing to do IMHO), since all typing information is lost anyway, there is little choice but to resort to a copy.

Comment: Lastly, the system I'm working on is a refactoring of my own code. The  system is incredibly stable, incredibly efficient network message passing library. It's been running for 10 years, the current revision for nearly 6. The complexity in the under-the-hood has largely prevented the devs working with it from making silly mistakes that kill the clients or servers due to networking, excepting a few cases, and I've had success in employing C++11 techniques to help the compiler work those out for them.

Comment: Your variant requires the *caller* to allocate an object and pass a pointer to it, and then `memcpy`()s the contents into the object. My variant marshals the data directly into the object. If we were constructing a X byte object with yours, you'd have to malloc X bytes of heap, populate them, then pass the address to Message::Message(), which would then either malloc() a second X bytes and transfer the object into that or it would copy it onto the heap.

Comment: With the existing system or the C++11 variant, the construction is done once. By using templates, the Message::Message() constructor actually provides the singular destination for the object to be constructed in. The object doesn't get constructed outside the Message::Message constructor.

Comment: It looks like you are taking my suggestions as personal atacks. I simply noted that the whole system seemed overcomplicated to me, especially when it boils down to preventing a less than 64 bytes copy. My advice is that in-place construction is unnecessary, and besides I don't think C++11 supports it, as the other answer clearly states.

Comment: Not taken as attacks, just trying to distinguish whether you simply have a very limited understanding of what you're discussing or if you're missing something in my question. When I say many of the messages are less than 64 bytes, that's because we're dealing with 10s of thousands of messages per second.

Comment: What my code does is : the message contents is created by the caller. The message constructor takes ownership of the contents. If it is less than 64 bytes, it is copied and deleted. If it is bigger, the message retains a reference to it without any copy. The object is destroyed when the message is. The cost for small messages is a new/delete plus a copy of less than 64 bytes. If I had to do it, I would drop the whole small buffer thing and replace it with a custom allocator drawing from a pool of pre-allocated 64 bytes buffers, so that the message system would not have to bother with all that.

Comment: "especially when it boils down to preventing a less than 64 bytes cope" no, it boils down to avoiding *copies* and needlessly polluting cache or inducing memory transfers, it certainly involves not having to perform an alloc on every call to the system - the "minimum message buffer" in systems like these (see raknet for a parallel comparison) allows you to get your entire message in a single allocation in many cases. You're going to have to take my word on this, it's necessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46818/discussion-between-kuroi-neko-and-kfsone)

Comment: It doesn't take ownership -- it allocates memory and bitwise copies to the new location. That's *broken* for non-trivial C++ objects. And do you realize that "new", "realloc" and "delete" all involve a mutex call? For the vast majority of messages, my class is entirely on the stack, and by forwarding construction of the sub-object into my constructor, I can do it *all* on the stack.

Comment: My question is *specifically* about *using C++11* tools to achieve a result, not about trying to solve a particular problem. While I appreciate your efforts to try and assist with problems you see in this highly-derivative rendering of a *very-high* performance message passing system, those solutions are both unecessary and not very good - e.g what you've achieved is basically the pre-C++11 macro that I included in my original post, `CONSTRUCT_IN_PLACE` and in your `BuildMessage...Gizmo("Hi")` you create a temporary "Gizmo" which BuildMessage then has to copy into the message itself.

Comment: The issues you identify (wasted memory, etc) are mostly artefacts of my hoisting only a part of the code, and not providing detailed insight into what the system does. Your comment about the template creating an extra forwarding is absolutely incorrect, unless you are referring to the very last version in my OP *which is the version I'm asking a question about whether it's possible to do with C++11 tricks*. The previous versions all avoid temporaries and copies and perform in-place news on the serialized objects. You'll have to take my word for this or consult the assembly.

Comment: I'm talking about my own code. In my example the message payload constructors are called within the message constructor, so the parameters have to be passed twice. I don't see how you could avoid that without calling the payload constructor directly (like in the macro solution). As for the "gizmo" thing, it was just there to materialize the double forwarding of arguments. Obviously it would not work in a real use case.

Comment: Anyway, this question of yours provided me with a practical example of C++11 templating, which I found interesting. My solution boils down to a variation of the other answer, i.e. derive a class that is aware of the size and arguments of the message payload constructor to defer the constructor call until after the proper memory location has been chosen. As for dynamic allocations, except for the explicit one in case of big messages, I don't see where any occur in my example. I'm sorry if it does not suit your needs.